# c++ ternary operator conversion understanding

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I cannot understand this ternary operator's conversion logic (here is an example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <climits>

template<typename T>
struct singletime
{
private:
    T               value;
public: 
    T& operator()() {return this->value;}

    operator const  T& () const {return value;}
    unsigned char   flag_needed_for_all_types;
};

static void getvalue1 (uint64_t value, const char *call)
{
    std::cout << call << ": \t" << value << std::endl << std::endl;
}

#define getvalue(x, str) \
std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl; \
getvalue1(x, str);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool flag = true;
    singletime<uint64_t> singletime_64;
    singletime_64() = INT_MAX+1lu;

    uint64_t value_64 = singletime_64;

    getvalue (flag ? singletime_64 : 0, "Ternary with singletime, > INT_MAX");
    getvalue (singletime_64, "singletime w/o ternary, > INT_MAX");

    getvalue (flag ? value_64 : 0, "Ternary with uint64_t, > INT_MAX");
    getvalue (value_64, "uint64_t w/o ternary, > INT_MAX");


    singletime_64() = INT_MAX;

    uint64_t value_64_l = singletime_64;

    getvalue (flag ? singletime_64 : 0, "Ternary with singletime, <= INT_MAX");
    getvalue (singletime_64, "singletime w/o ternary, <= INT_MAX");

    getvalue (flag ? value_64_l : 0, "Ternary with uint64_t, <= INT_MAX");
    getvalue (value_64_l, "uint64_t w/o ternary, <= INT_MAX");

    return 0;
}
```

I have a template class `singletime<T>`, which is a wrapper of any type, used for cases, not related to this question and has a conversion operator to `T`. The issue is when `singletime<uint64_t>` is used in a ternary operator expression.

This is the problematic line:

```
getvalue (flag ? singletime_64 : 0, "Ternary with singletime, > INT_MAX");
```

The 64-bit value is converted to int and if the value is above `INT_MAX`, it becomes incorrect.

The example prints some usage types of the ternary operator - with the resulting type of the expression and resulting value.
Here is the output of the example:

```
int
Ternary with singletime, > INT_MAX:     18446744071562067968

singletime<unsigned long>
singletime w/o ternary, > INT_MAX:  2147483648

unsigned long
Ternary with uint64_t, > INT_MAX:   2147483648

unsigned long
uint64_t w/o ternary, > INT_MAX:    2147483648

int
Ternary with singletime, <= INT_MAX:    2147483647

singletime<unsigned long>
singletime w/o ternary, <= INT_MAX:     2147483647

unsigned long
Ternary with uint64_t, <= INT_MAX:  2147483647

unsigned long
uint64_t w/o ternary, <= INT_MAX:   2147483647
```

The only problem is when the ternary operator is used with `singletime<uint64_t>` - it gets the value 18446744071562067968

As I understand, it tries to convert different types to one type.

As there is conversion operator from `singletime<uint64_t>` to `uint64_t`, it maybe uses it, but after that I don't understand why it converts both values to int, instead of `uint64_t`? In examples where `uint64_t` is used instead of `singletime<uint64_t>`, the int is converted to `uint64_t` and no values are lost

In the case of `singletime<uint64_t>` and int, there is also no compiler warning about cast to smaller type and potential data loss.

Tried with gcc 4.8.2 and gcc 5.2.0

Answer (score 6):

From standard, 5.16.

> if the second and third operand have different types, and either has
>   (possibly cv-qualified) class type, an attempt is made to convert each
>   of those operands to the type of the other. The process for determining whether an operand expression E1 of type T1 can be converted to
>   match an operand expression E2 of type T2 is defined as follows:
>
> If E2 is an rvalue, or if the conversion above cannot be done:
>
> Otherwise (i.e., if E1 or E2 has a nonclass type, or if they both have
>   class types but the underlying classes are not either the same or one
>   a base class of the other): E1 can be converted to match E2 if E1 can
>   be implicitly converted to the type that expression E2 would have if
>   E2 were converted to an rvalue (or the type it has, if E2 is an
>   rvalue).
>
> If the second and third operand do not have the same type, and either
>   has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, overload resolution is used to
>   determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands
>   (13.3.1.2, 13.6).

So, here, 0 is rvalue and it has type `int`. Compiler will try to convert first argument to `int` and it will do that, cause that can be done, due to your conversion operator.